# How can I call class methods dynamically?

Tags: typescript, oop, methods, error-handling, abstract-class

I am trying to make an abstract class with method `callAction` which calls methods of class dynamically.

I have tried to write this but I am getting error.

```
abstract export class BaseContoller {
    public callAction(method: keyof typeof this, parameters: any[]) {
        this[method](parameters);
    }
}
```

Error - This expression is not callable. Type 'unknown' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

Is there another way to achive this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript. Filtering functional properties and \`Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075560/typescript-filtering-functional-properties-and-cannot-invoke-an-expression-who)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class can have value as well as function properties together, so to make sure your property is a function type, you can use `typeof x === "function"`.

That can help to check `method`'s type with the call signature before method execution.

```
class BaseContoller {
    public callAction(method: keyof typeof this, parameters: any[]) {
      const property = this[method]
      if(typeof property === "function") {
        property(parameters);
      }
    }

    public testFunction() {}
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDCB7AdgFxSECBO0A3gLABQ0F0ADgK4BGIAlsNMGDgILAaPoAUAWwQYAFigAmALmgBrBAE8UAM2gZ5VBMtUjGEADTUweMEIz4I0sGnkBtALoBKImUqVg6CBmp4UGvGugAXm1dG1MxcTsXV2hGJT41DS0qHz8AwIzoAHIlGjRuXjQspxJyGIoU33w1PiojE2FzBwBuaNcAXzboTtIu2gZmVQRPADE8gv4Snp6yNAQAdzhEVExsXDw%20BwA6Nk4JtD4ss1HxnnQsg3sHMlmFpYhkdCwcfE2d9hAuM4Oj4Ywx-LfACMF2gV2gAHoIfgfHggA)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible for static-code validation to know, at compile time, the subclasses involved. Therefore you can't do that unless you throw away type checking altogether and cast `this` as `any` first.

Instead, I think you'll have to settle for other code calling your child class methods directly if you want the benefits of Typescript's type checking.

It might be smarter to assert type safety at run time.